# Creating a more responsive android notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am interested in what the current best practice for android API 16 is when it comes to changing a notification button.

Currently I set the bigContentView and use **setOnClickPendingIntent()** to make callbacks to the service but I'm finding the notification to be really slow at being updated as it has to change one of the button images between two different states (like toggling play/pause).

After logging ive traced it down to the code of swapping the drawable button.

```
setImageViewResource(viewId, srcId);
```

Takes anywhere from 1.0s - 0.3s which is a noticable delay for the user, surely there must be a better way? Or something I'm blatantly missing?

Any suggestions to avoid the update delay or any feedback on my current implementation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the two ImageViews above each other and switch the visibility between them. This way you will only need to load them once and you will avoid many Garbage Collection calls that could result in slow responsiveness in your app and you can also scale down your resources to a smaller size.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot believe I never thought of that. Sweet, I'll try it when I get off work, but I reckon this could be the trick. :)